# If the whole world suffered a massive EMP attack, how long would it take for people to forget how to build modern technology?

Tags: post-apocalypse

After a devastating war culminating in a global blackout via atmospheric EMPs, how long would it take for human civilization to devolve to a medieval level of technology? Hundreds of years? Thousands? Would it even happen like that at all or would society rebuild itself before it got that far?

Comment: How are you proposing a continuous EMP. They happen, then stop. If they don't then you're probably going to die from it or may as well consider it death because your cognitive faculties will be destroyed after a while, among other things that will malfunction in the body.

Comment: As Durakken is saying, an EMP is not normally continuous. It literally stands for "electromagnetic _pulse_", which indicates a one-shot event. Sure, it's going to suck if we end up with some worldwide EMP. It's going to fry some hardware. We're going to lose an awful lot of data, some of it irreplaceable. But enough will survive for humanity to reconstruct the essential software and hardware. I'd be more worried about this devastating war scenario you have just before the EMP strike: this strongly suggests the use of nuclear weapons, which makes nuclear winter a much more serious problem.

Comment: I'm not proposing a prolonged or continuous EMP. I just don't know how much of our tech has been EMP-proofed.

Comment: Relatively little.  Anytime you stick a radio in something, you invite EMP damage.  Even electronics without radios are vulnerable to EMP.  The manufacturer has to be really careful in the design to avoid damage/destruction.

Comment: There are also a lot of unstated variables in this question.  How many people died in the war?  How much damage to infrastructure was there?  Were the technically adept portions of the population especially hard hit?  Are the major urban centers still intact?

Comment: @Green EMP can travel along power lines as well. Virtually all commercial electronics is successable to EMP. The military has some hardened electronics but even those can be affected. You have to build a faraday cage to fully protect yourself.

Comment: @ventsyv What makes EMP *really* nasty is that it can strike the middle of your circuit, in places you never thought you could need to protect.  While EMP will absolutely travel along power lines, and may acquire some pretty spectacular voltages in some cases, that's also the direction we deal with lightning strikes from.  Far more of our products are protected against lighting strikes... especially the things people people find important enough to protect.

Comment: I also found (this table)[http://midimagic.sgc-hosting.com/emp.htm] which seemed rather interesting on the topic.

Comment: Essentially, if your electronics aren't designed to withstand a direct lighting strike to the circuit they are on, they aren't going to survive the EMP of the sort you're thinking of.

Comment: Haven't we already done this one to death from various angles on this site?

Answer (score 17):

Technology would never fall to a medieval level due to the aftermath of war and a global EMP.

For one thing, we have textbooks that are present in millions of households and tens of thousands of schools, and have several thousand university libraries, each of which would have much of the key tech in print, and that information could be reclaimed faster than the books would decay.

Also lots of the barriers to first time around science and technology development were due to conceptual barriers like incorrect worldview that no one alive at the time of the event and no one raised and taught with books from before the event would labor under. World views tend to be stable over time; people don't suddenly become more superstitious and ignorant than they are to start with, especially if the war itself leaves behind people who remember life before the war. Afghanistan hasn't fully regressed to a medieval state and its been in a low tech state of constant war for thirty plus years.

And, while war ruins a lot of functional mechanisms, it tends to leave the raw materials more or less where they were. So, for example, you could get iron from a junk yard or derelict building or defunct hardware store or warehouse, rather than having to mine it underground and purify it in large scale industrial operations. You wouldn't have to go half way around to world to get platinum when you could just raid some catalytic converters, or rare earths which could be obtained from busted up mechanisms that use them.

Also there are many machines (my son's 1992 Mazda Miata, older diesel trucks and construction equipment, guns including machine guns, telescopes, microscopes, glass and ceramic forges, bicycles, windup clocks like grandfather clocks and winding watches, sail boats, row boats, lawn mowers, water pump windmills, ladders, pulleys, hand winches, scaffolding, hand pumps, older oil wells, gas lamps, hot air balloons, gliders, diesel powered cable cars, pianos, guitars, lazy susans, most plumbing systems, gas stoves, and steam boilers among them) that exhibit considerable technological advances without actually being heavily dependent upon electronics of types that are vulnerable to an EMP.

Certainly, a massive war culminating in this way would not be good for the economy - it might even be worse than the Great Depression. And, it would require a little innovation. But, it would be far more likely to set us back a generation or two tops (1950s to 1980sish), than to set us back a millennium or more.

Comment: global thermonuclear war could do that. The population centers will be destroyed and rendered inaccessible for a long time so that knowledge will be largely lost. "A Canticle for Leibowitz" describes just such scenario.

Comment: I honestly don't think any global thermonuclear war that enough humans survived to prevent us from going extinct would do that. There aren't enough nuclear weapons in the world to wipe out every decent library in the world and fill everyone's mind with new less accurate world views. Even a single small town or high school library would keep us a long way from hitting bottom.

Comment: Your county public library has very little in terms of engineering or basic science. I doubt you can find enough to build a bridge for example.

Comment: You'd be surprised. There'd be physics textbooks, science fair books, dozens of books on famous bridges for every age level from little kids to adults, the Handbook of Chemistry and Physics providing lots of strength of materials data, some books on the military or technology history that would touch on military engineering in ways pertinent to bridges, dictionaries defining bridge types, encyclopedias setting forth the big points. Metallurgy books would be hard to find, but books and magazines on home improvement, wood, cement and on the concept of reinforced cement would be easy to locate.

Comment: @ventsyv You would also be surprised how large a percentage of the population has practical first hand knowledge of how to make things. Lots of people have worked in construction or as mechanics or as farmers or in a skilled trade or in a machine shop or in craft hobbies or in the military at some point in life (all populations which are underrepresented among college grads). Those skills would become extra valuable when it was not longer possibly to rely on factories half the world away and professional engineers. Their valuable skills would be rewarded and thus passed on as a livelihood.

Comment: @everyone It's also remarkable how much of a difference it makes to know that something is possible. Humanity won't soon lose track of the technology it had, giving it a great road map of how to come back. Even a high school history textbook gives you a decent idea of what order to go through in rebuilding.

Comment: If a capable engineer survives, chances are *really* good that you have library *as well as* someone who understands and is motivated to use it.

Answer (score 6):

First off, society wouldn't rebuild itself.  Society would build something new that fits with the environment it is in.  We would not say "aww darn, we lost everything.  Time to work for 500 years to build a DOS computer."  Society would go in a different direction.

Thus, to ask how long it would take would require us to delve into your particular metric of what the concept of rebuilding means.  Someone who defines their life around an ancient art (such as a kung fu discipline or pottery) may find that we "rebuild" by their definition very quickly.  Someone who lives and dies by what their social media feed is doing and what the latest celebrity gossip is may find that their definition of "rebuild" takes a whole lot longer.

That being said, the amount of time it takes to rebuild after a devistating war culminating in a global blackout via atmospheric EMPs is almost exactly as long as it would take after a devistating war that doesn't culminate in a blackout.  EMPs are not as bad as you make them sound.  You can harden electronics against them.  You can also store things on media which are resistant to EMP.  Only slightly tongue in cheek: paper is highly resistant to EMP.

So the real question is how did this war play out.  The EMPs would be a minor inconvenience not worth mentioning in the shadow of the kind of war that caused the EMPs to occur in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You can protect against EMP by building Faraday cages. Presumably the world governments do protect their critical military equipment against EMP.

GAO published a report a few years ago on the topic and it updates it occasionally. [The last update](http://www.cnsnews.com/news/article/barbara-hollingsworth/gao-report-us-remains-vulnerable-emp-attack) concluded that the US is still not sufficiently prepared for an EMP. 
Congress also holds hearings occasionally. [Here is the testimonial of one of the witnesses in one of those hearings.](https://oversight.house.gov/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Baker-Statement-5-13-EMP.pdf)

Protecting buildings against EMP is very expensive (I've heard ~20% of the cost of the building for new buildings) and it's fairly unlikely event. Private industry is dispursing their data centers to be closer to their users and are getting the unintended benefit of EMP protection.

In a case of a global EMP, the grid will probably be knocked down and stay down for an extended period of time. Private industry will be wiped out but government will survive at some level. In addition the knowledge will not disappear. The science discoveries and engineering books are in the libraries, if the government manages to save enough experts, they'll be able to rebuild eventually.

Obviously it all hinges on how much law and order remains. If civil war and anarchy ensues and continues for a long time (100 years for example) I can see it possible that humanity regresses to early industrial revolution, but I doubt we'll go back all the way back to mediavel times.

Comment: So, worst case scenario back to late 18th century, early 19th century in technology in your view?

Comment: Yeah, that's right.

Comment: There's even an [apocalypse survival treasure trove](http://www.survivorlibrary.com/) that people have *printed out* just in case of an event like the one described.

Answer (score 2):

Books aren't affected by EMPs.  As long as people can read, the knowledge isnt lost and can always be retained.  We live in a post Gutenberg world....information storage would just go back to pre-computer days and not change much.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding.SE! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

They wouldn't forget.  They wouldn't have time to forget.

A massive EMP attack would take out a lot of infrastructure, including lots of data.  It would be a pretty big deal - especially once the secondary effects were counted, the side effects of whatever caused the EMP, or even if it happened on its own, the direct results of electronics failures, like the death toll in hospitals and loss of electronics on airplanes needed to fly or land (therefore crashes), and the financial repercussions would be terrible because of the loss of data.

But, there are ways to harden electronics against EMPs (used by the military, so some of their systems should survive), there are backups and hard copies of data - not everything, but lots of things, including blueprints, books, and other sources of information and technology.  And there are lots of people that remember, to cover some of the gaps that remain.  The bigger question was how much was damaged by the accompanying war, and even more, how much was changed during that war - is there enough of a system left to survive on while everything got rebuilt, what system was it, were people setting up backups because they knew EMPs could be used, was hardening being distributed.  People could manually be arranging transport of necessary supplies, trading physical objects and favors, keeping track of logistics so that once everything was up and running again, there would be records - they might have switched over to such systems at the threat of EMPs, before the actual event, or they might have been caught of guard.

If the EMP is a singular event, the infrastructure would simply be rebuilt, and perhaps upgraded.  It would take time and resources, but it would also be a priority.  There would be time for a real loss of knowledge, I would suspect rebuilding would begin as soon as the attack ended.  People already know how to make, repair, and troubleshoot the stuff in place, it would be straightforward to replace - the real trouble will be dealing with the rest of the event, like what caused the EMP (if it was accompanied by an explosion (nukes make EMPs)?  was it a weapon for a war?  what other things happened at the same time?).

If the EMP is continuous, or repetitive, so that electronics keep getting disrupted and destroyed - it would take some time for technology to reach the same level again.  And if the war damage was very bad, it might take some time for people to come together, and get enough surplus to be a buffer against immediate needs, and have the time to start rebuilding everything.

Even so I doubt society would devolve to medieval levels of tech  - we simply have too much knowledge, too many records, of every advance that's happened since then, and no reason not to use every improvement we could.  Every mechanical and chemical process that has been discovered remains intact, for example, biological advances (selected varieties, hybrids or GMO that may breed true) will still be in place.  There are textbooks, there are specialists, there are end-of-the-world survivalists with plans for what knowledge would be most immediately useful and plans for rebuilding...

People wouldn't forget because the knowledge is valuable, and even when they are still looking for ways to fill their most basic needs, they will be trying to spend any spare effort will go to remembering, finding knowledge, and rebuilding - because they will all remember that that knowledge is how they can reach a state where they don't have to spend every energy on mere survival.  They will be too busy actively looking for ways to put knowledge to use, to dare let it be forgotten.

I expect it wouldn't actually take too long for people to start coming up with EMP hardened electronics again, even if they're simple and with manual backups for when they fail.  Electronics would be simpler and sturdier, and once again restricted to major systems and urgent needs until the processes are worked out enough to make them cost-efficient for regular consumers again - sort of like how they were developed the first time, only with the double incentive of knowing what should be possible, and having a large market that knows what they want, quickly.

Comment: What a lot of people seem to forget or not understand is that the world of the modern age was built by less than half the current world's population in less than half a human life span. The reason we dont improve a lot of it is because that would be "expensive", but thats only cuz it works. It is a lot more expensive to let it break and not fix it than it is to fix and improve it at that point. A lot of us would be without internet for a while, but once we understood what happened power would be restored within weeks to months, & internet within a few years to a decade assuming no other issue.

Comment: @Durakken - that was my first thought - between that and places I've seen where power outages are really, really common (so they may have electronics but don't rely on them), all point to the fact the loss of electronics would be expensive, but assuming no other issue, completely fixable and *quickly*.  The "devastating war" OP mentions might be a different matter, but honestly I didn't even see it mentioned on the first read-through.

Answer (score 1):

Anywhere from a single day to a year. An EMP is not a continuous event. Watch the Matrix. The first one. The ship used an EMP to kill the machines, and in the meantime, they turned everything off, so that their electronics wouldn't be fried in the process. So depending on how far away it was from the source of the EMP, any equipment that wasn't on at the time or not plugged in would still be able to build new stuff, which would be sorely needed. And we would still know how to build things because plans aren't just on computers. There are hard, paper copies of things out there.

Plus, there are plenty of advancements that are EMP proof, which we already know how to build. Tech from 100 years ago is still being used.
The war itself would have to be responsible for wiping out a lot of infrastructure to begin with, and industry would adapt. There would have to be lots of EMP events in order for this to slow us down, and even then, we would build EMP resistant tech.

Somewhere out there someone has written a government paper responding to this scenario, because we already know it's possible. Right now we aren't prepared for it, but that doesn't mean there aren't people who haven't thought about it, and it doesn't mean that we can't respond when it does happen.

Answer (score 0):

It simply depends on access to recorded information.  Without books a small group of people would probably "Forget" nearly everything immediately.  If you took 6 random people into a power plant without any specific information and said "Get this working" there is a pretty low chance of lasting success.  If the plant is damaged the chance trends to zero quickly unless one of your people happened to start with applicable knowledge.

If you took a batch of children today and "raised" them without access to information or "Training" of any sort you'd have nothing but cave-men.  They would probably survive on instinct, but they would have to re-create speech, writing and... well it would be a complete reset.

Without books (by this I mean recorded information) any group would be lost.  With enough time, motivation and books (and the ability to read them), any group could solve any problem.

Our entire civilization is based on the ability to record & access information.  Take that away (alone, no further disaster required) and our technology will quickly become unsustainable.